# Emacs strange key conflict

Tags: emacs, gnome

In Emacs I often get a box popping activated, but I don't know how it does activate nor how to deactivate it, because it is cryptic, I don't know what it is.

The box is conflicting with a very recurrent and ordinary Emacs command I use A LOT (it marks from the point to the end of the line), every time I press ctrl + shift + e, I get the box (in the point) overriding the Emacs command, making it unusable.

I run Emacs 25 over GNU/Linux Fedora 25 with GNOME 3 desktop environment. I checked the key combinations descriptions of GNOME, none of them has anything to do with the problem. Emacs is the only program I get the box once it gets "activated".

Restarting session nor the computer doesn't fix it. Reinstalling everything clean doesn't fix the problem either. To temporarily solve, I restart session to GNOME classic and the problem goes away, once the problem reappears in classic, then I start session back to standard, and so on.

---

Here is an image sample of the problem, see the dark grey box with the '@' character:

[image]

---

Another sample, when the box is showing, if I type anything:
[image]

---

Alternatively, when the box is showing, if I do ctrl+x I get:
[image]

---

I am not sure this problem origins from updating the software, neither sure if it is just an Emacs problem, or in combination with another program (Fedora/GNOME). I have spent quite a lot of time searching, but I don't even know how to describe this thing to "google it" successfully, have not found any documentation from Emacs nor GNOME about this strange functionality.

**What is and how to deactivate the dialogue?**

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball tells me that there's probably a "ctrl + shift + e" binding in your environment (i.e. probably in some Gnome stuff).

At least I'm pretty sure this box doesn't come from Emacs.

I'd recommend you go take a look at your system preferences.